# What is the domain name for a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, twitch

I am currently building a Google Chrome extension displaying a Twitch player within the extension window. To do so I need to have the domain / website on which the extension is hosted. In this case I guess it would be Google Chrome but I don't quite understand hwo to get the exact domain name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a domain name, as in something like stackoverflow.com or google.com etc? "Google Chrome" is not a domain or a website, it's a fairly popular web browser, you may have heard of it since you're writing an extension for it ... can you please explain why you think you need a domain / website to host the extension? links to documentation that has led you to believe this etc

Comment: Why do need the domain name to embed the player? What's different to a youtube player?

Comment: Hi, sorry If my question was rather nebulous but I'm new to Stackoverflow.
I am trying to embed a Twitch livestream within a Chrome extension window.
Twitch used to provide a simple iframe that I could just copy paste but now it seems they ask for the "parent". That is, **Domain(s) that will be embedding Twitch. You must have one parent key for each domain your site uses** as per defined by the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> To do so I need to have the domain / website on which the extension is hosted.

They aren't hosted on any domain at all, they're loaded directly by Chrome from its local copy of the extension. The scheme used in the URL is `chrome-extension://`, not `http://` or `https://`. For instance:

```
chrome-extension://longstringofcharactershere/filename.html
```

If you need to provide Twitch with a domain (for instance, to get passlisted in their CORS policy or some such), there's simply no domain to give them. (I haven't tried, but Chrome extensions are really locked down by default, I doubt you could even embed an `iframe` loaded from a domain you control. Extensions are a privacy and security nightmare, so Google locks them down pretty thoroughly.)